# Nothing prints after piping ping through two commands

Tags: bash, pipe, ping

Running this:

```
ping google.com | grep -o 'PING'
```

Will print `PING` to the terminal, so I assume that means that the stdout of grep was captured by the terminal.

So why doesn't the follow command print anything? The terminal just hangs:

```
ping google.com | grep -o 'PING' | grep -o 'IN'
```

I would think that the stdout of the first grep command would be redirected to the stdin of the second grep. Then the stdout of the second grep would be captured by the terminal and printed.

This seems to be what happens if ping is replaced with echo:

```
echo 'PING' | grep -o 'PING' | grep -o 'IN'
```

`IN` is printed to the terminal, as I would expect.

So what's special about `ping` that prevents anything from being printed?

Comment: learn about grep's `--line-buffered` option. It'll solve your issue

Comment: Try `ping -c 5` so it stops after 5 tries.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thanks! but I'm not sure why that option makes it work or how to generalize the solution. This problem also exists for other commands, like perl: `ping google.com | perl -pe '' | grep -o 'IN'` outputs nothing as well, and perl doesn't seem to have the same option.

Comment: This might help: `man 1 stdbuf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try being more patient :-)

```
ping google.com | grep -o 'PING' | grep -o 'IN'
```

will *eventually* display output, but it might take half an hour or so.

Under Unix, the standard output stream handed to a program when it starts up is "line-buffered" if the stream is a terminal; otherwise it is fully buffered, typically with a buffer of 8 kilobytes (8,192 characters). Buffering means that output is accumulated in memory until the buffer is full, or, in the case of line-buffered streams, until a newline character is sent.

Of course, a program can override this setting, and programs which produce only small amounts of output -- like `ping` -- typically make stdout line-buffered regardless of what it is. But `grep` does not do so (although you can tell Gnu grep to do that by using the `--line-buffered` command-line option.)

"Pipes" (which are created to implement the `|` operator) are not considered terminals. So the `grep` in the middle will have a fully-buffered output, meaning that its output will be buffered until 8k characters are written. That will take a while in your case, because each line contains only five characters (`PING` plus a newline), and they are produced once a aecond. So the buffer will fill up after about 1640 seconds, which is almost 28 minutes.

Many unix distributions come with a program called `stdbuf` which can be used to change buffering for standard streams before running a program. (If you have `stdbuf`, you can find out how it works by typing `man 1 stdbuf`.) Programming languages like Perl generally provide other mechanisms to call the `stdbuf` standard library function. (In Perl, you can force a flush after every write using the builtin variable `$|`, or the `autoflush(BOOL)` io handle method.)

Of course, when a program successfully terminates, all output buffers are "flushed" (srnt to their respective streams). So

```
echo PING | grep -o 'PING' | grep -o 'IN'
```

will immediately output its only output line. But `ping` does not terminate unless you provide a count command-line option (`-c N`; see `man ping`). So if you need immediate piped throughput, you may need to modify buffering behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Unfortunately I don't have stdbuf on my system, but why researching some of the stuff you mentioned, I came across https://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html

It seems like "$|=1" disables buffering in perl by making stdout "hot". So this:

`ping google.com | perl -pe '$|=1' | grep -o 'IN'`

Will print "IN" immediately.